# CSS Class - font color dependent on value (in a table)

Tags: html, css

I have a plugin for creating tables from MySQL data in Wordpress. 
There is a possibility to define CSS classes and I'm able to do simple ones e.g.:

```
date {font-size: 12px; color: #497E9E; font-weight: bold;}
```

However, I was wondering if there is any simple way of doing class based on value: e.g.

Red if value is negative.
Green if value is positive.

Is it possible, or do I need some script to check it for me and then use defined classes?

Comment: Based on content with pure CSS, no. But if the numbers are also stored inside HTML attributes, e.g. `<span data-number="123">123</span>`, we could do something. Could you post a sample of the HTML output? Or you could use JS, if that's an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a jQuery method to itterate through all the classes called div-check and set it to red/green based on positive or negative.

You could alter this to get the data attribute from a field or get the value from a table row.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $( ".div-check" ).each(function(){
       var value = parseInt( $( this ).html() );
       if ( value < 0 )
       {
           $( this ).parent().css('color', 'red');
       }else{
           $( this ).parent().css('color', 'green');
       }

   });
});
```

Comment: Apparently there is no way yet to do that only with CSS. You will need Javascript. Doing with jQuery as Darren suggest you is pretty nice solution.